# Facing error while copy files from local to shiny server in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, shiny, shiny-server

I'm trying to copy the shinyapp files from local to remote(shiny server).

```
scp -r "D:/Testing/Test_04_11_2023" lincy@localhost:/srv/shiny-server/
```

my username is lincy, and my hostname is localhost, but (Host key verification failed.
ssh: Could not resolve hostname d: Name or service not known) this error occurs when i run that code in ubuntu terminal.